# How to get sqlite database Values in javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, database, sqlite

i need how to get values from sqlite Database for particular columns records in Javascript, i successfully inserted values in DB but do no how to fetch the values from db

Here my sample code how i inserted :

```
var newPath1 = __dirname + path.sep+'schedule.sqlite'
var bfr = fs.readFileSync(newPath1)
var db = new sql.Database(bfr)
db.run("INSERT into 
profile_id(SNo,visit_id,date,time,profile_url,First_Name,Last_Name) VALUES 
(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
[result,result1,date1,time1,sampleUrl,first_Name,last_Name])
var data = db.export();
var buffer = new Buffer(data);
fs.writeFileSync(newPath1, buffer);
```

i need a solution from this DB i need to fetch all values from **First_Name**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading info from sqlite database, Syntax? How do I use it in html5 webapp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122057/reading-info-from-sqlite-database-syntax-how-do-i-use-it-in-html5-webapp)

Comment: i tried that but i'm getting 'db.transaction' not defined

Comment: first c my question how i inserted and what method i have been used based on that give me solution

Comment: I see no `db.transaction` in your code. Please check the scope of your `db` variable.

Comment: i already tried that above example which u mentioned above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the solution

```
var fName =  db.exec("SELECT First_Name FROM profile_id")
```

this code works

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT into 
profile_id(SNo,visit_id,date,time,profile_url,First_Name,Last_Name) VALUES 
(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");  

  stmt.run(result,result1,date1,time1,sampleUrl,first_Name,last_Name);  

  stmt.finalize();  

  db.each("SELECT First_Name FROM profile_id", function(err, row) {  
      console.log("First Name : "+row.First_Name);  
  });
```

Comment: i'm getting this error on my console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'First_Name' of undefined"